# Adding form field values together into hidden field on form submit (js or jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

this seems super simple to me, but I just can't figure it out today.

I've developed a basic quiz, and want to add the answers of the quiz together to create a "score". Based on the score I'll return different results on the confirmation page.

Here's a basic example of the form:

```
<form id="quiz" method="post" name="quiz" action="url">
<label for="field1">Question 1</label>
<label><input name="question1" value="1" type="radio">Answer 1</label>
<label><input name="question1" value="4" type="radio">Answer 2</label>
<label><input name="question1" value="9" type="radio">Answer 3</label>

<label for="field2">Question 2</label>
<label><input name="question2" value="1" type="radio">Answer 1</label>
<label><input name="question2" value="4" type="radio">Answer 2</label>
<label><input name="question2" value="9" type="radio">Answer 3</label>

<label for="field3">Question 3</label>
<label><input name="question3" value="1" type="radio">Answer 1</label>
<label><input name="question3" value="4" type="radio">Answer 2</label>
<label><input name="question3" value="9" type="radio">Answer 3</label>

<input value="See your Results" type="submit">
</form>
```

I tried building out some javascript to add these values together, but it wasn't even beginning to work - here's my attempt in case you're curious:

```
function generateScore(){
    var maturityScore = document.forms[0].question1.value + document.forms[0].question2.value + document.forms[0].question1.value;
    document.forms[0].maturityLevel.value = maturityScore;
}

document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit') = generateScore
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Happy to use javascript or jquery to do this. Note that I can't edit the form html - it's being generated by the MAP I'm using (and is way ugly - the version I posted above is simplified for readability).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```js
$('#quiz').on('submit',function(){
var score = parseInt($('input[name=question1]:checked').val())+
            parseInt($('input[name=question2]:checked').val())+
            parseInt($('input[name=question3]:checked').val());
alert('submit'+score);
//score can be assigned to any field you need
//$('#maturityLevel').val(score);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="quiz" method="post" name="quiz" action="url">
<label for="field1">Question 1</label>
<label><input name="question1" value="1" type="radio">Answer 1</label>
<label><input name="question1" value="4" type="radio">Answer 2</label>
<label><input name="question1" value="9" type="radio">Answer 3</label>

<label for="field2">Question 2</label>
<label><input name="question2" value="1" type="radio">Answer 1</label>
<label><input name="question2" value="4" type="radio">Answer 2</label>
<label><input name="question2" value="9" type="radio">Answer 3</label>

<label for="field3">Question 3</label>
<label><input name="question3" value="1" type="radio">Answer 1</label>
<label><input name="question3" value="4" type="radio">Answer 2</label>
<label><input name="question3" value="9" type="radio">Answer 3</label>

<input value="See your Results" type="submit">
</form>
```

Make sure to answer all the 3 question. Otherwise you have to do the proper validations before parsing using `parseInt`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This worked perfectly. You are a star :D